# Google calendar embed issue: mobile

Tags: html, css, calendar, shopify, google-calendar-api

I have no way of contacting google directly regarding this otherwise I’d go bug them. I’m noticing that google calendar is not showing up on any mobile view and I’m wondering what could be the issue:

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=800&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23ffffff&amp;ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles&amp;src=Z2Jqai5vcmdfNzFtbTMwbjdkMzY1b2RianJsYWdtbnZjMGdAZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&amp;color=%23B39DDB&amp;showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;mode=AGENDA" style="border-width: 0;" width="100%" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

My friend also has a site with google calendar embedded in the page, can’t see it via any mobile browser. Anything above look horribly wrong? I tried using the exact embed that google calendar spits out to no avail…here’s the page:

https://gbjj.org/pages/calendar

If this doesn’t resolve I’m going to have to find an alternative calendar solution, but I guess that’s neither here nor there and I’ll have to start shopping for something viable.

Comment: FYI. Also having the same issue. Most likely will get resolved on its on.

Comment: The two concerns I have are…1. No way to inform google that actually tells me they know what’s going on. 2. I think I need a different calendar tool…anyone have any suggestions with those? Sorry you’re having the same problem. Not fun at all.

Comment: I posted in google calendar help forums. you might want to chime in as well. https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/111009704/embedded-calendar-stopped-showing-on-mobile-devices-10-30p-5-23-21?hl=en&msgid=111009704

Comment: I have a couple old sites where this embed is not working now...I did notice that it does show up in the google setting page...@John...that page is not available

Comment: Anyone have an alternative calendar display recommendation??

Comment: If you can't resolve this using the plain Google Calendar embed, I'd recommend [Styled Calendar](https://styledcalendar.com/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=forum-posts). It's mobile responsive, easy to set up, and very customizable on the free plan.